# Need help with this weed. Can anyone identify and recommend treatment?

Tags: weed-control, weeds

I live in the northeast and just had new grass seed put down early spring.  The first one pulls out easily when it has matured, but when it’s small it grows between the lawn and is hard to pull out. It is literally taking over half of my lawn. Weed and feed has not worked.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please ask a separate question for the second plant. We have a policy of one plant per question; see https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/826/for-identification-please-only-post-one-plant-per-question-and-be-specific-whe for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I wish I knew myself.  It is taking over my lawn.  The worst part about it is that in the fall it dies, leaving bare spots where it crowded out the grass.

---

> UPDATE:

***  I stumbled on the answer a few minutes ago.  It is Japanese Stiltgrass! An invasive weed that will take over your lawn.  The good news is you can kill it with the following two produdcts: Acclaim Extra and Bayer Crabgrass Killer for Lawns.  I am getting some as soon as I can get to the store. Lowes, home Depot and Walmart carry the Bayer  You can read about it here:
https://njaes.rutgers.edu/fs1237/

Answer (score 0):

I tried the Bayer and it did nothing for me. Just ordered the Acclaim Extra to give it a try.